# Javascript value set null if value equals nothing

Tags: javascript

Right now I am working on a timesheet where users can set their in time, their out time, and how long they've been at lunch. Then I use a function that subtracts the in time & the lunch from their out time to figure out their hours, plus possible overtime. What I want is to have javascript set the value of the overtime field to '' (aka null) if the amount of time they were at work is 8 hours or less.

My code for checking overtime is this:

```
// Return difference between two times in hh:mm[am/pm] format as hh:mm
function checkOvertime(timein, timeout, away) {
  // Small helper function to pad single digits
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
  // Get difference in minutes
  var subtotal = daytimeStringToMins(timeout) - daytimeStringToMins(timein) - timeStringToMins(away);
  var regularhours = '08:00';
  if (subtotal > timeStringToMins(regularhours)) {var overtime = daytimeStringToMins(timeout) - daytimeStringToMins(timein) - timeStringToMins(away) - timeStringToMins(regularhours);}
    else {var overtime = '0';}
  return   z(overtime/60 | 0) + ':' + z(overtime % 60);
}
```

and then in my calculation function I have this:

```
if (checkOvertime(timein, timeout, away).value == '00:00') {
  document.getElementById("date-1-overtime").value = '';
} else {
  document.getElementById("date-1-overtime").value = checkOvertime(timein, timeout, away);
}
```

So if a person is at work for 8 hours, then the "date-1-overtime" field says "00:00" but I would like it to put nothing in there so the sheet prints out more cleanly.

I think maybe I am confusing the difference between strings and integers in the calculation functions but I'm not sure, hopefully someone could help me!

Comment: Note that `null` and zero, as in `0` is not the same thing

Comment: Yeah I specifically want the inputs to be empty so that nothing shows up in the table cells so that they're easier to read when the manager prints them out.

Comment: So you don't really want `null`, you want an empty string

Comment: I am happy to go with empty string if that's more correct. My understanding of the difference between strings, values, integers etc is pretty weak

Comment: I would go with empty string for sure. If it's really about appearance what would you prefer - `user - Jhon; Overtime - null` or `user - Jhon; Overtime - `. Even though `JavaScript` is pretty forgiving and you may end up with a blank space despite returning `null`, using empty string still makes your code more readable (at least in my opinion) and also this may save you some problems later on.

Comment: Is there a reason why "if (checkOvertime(timein, timeout, away).value == '00:00') {
  document.getElementById("date-1-overtime").value = '';
}" isn't currently returning an empty string? I'm fine with putting an empty string in there if that's what will work. I'd just like the emailed output to be a little cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this method to use regular expressions to extract the appropriate parts of the input and then use parseint to get the value in a numeric form.

Convert that to minutes and if the minutes are less than or equal to 480 (8 * 60), return the actual string.

Also, you can't really assign a null value to an html param. null is not the same as 0. null is essentially, undefined.

You should return the number of minutes worked overtime from your function and use 0 for overtime if the user didn't work overtime.